# React native mac run brew install cocoapods Error: cocoapods: Failed to download resource "cmake"

Tags: react-native

React native mac run **brew install cocoapods** Error: cocoapods: Failed to download resource "cmake"

Why? Below is the complete support process：

```
Mylaptop:rn-call-test lllomh$ brew install cocoapods
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
==> Homebrew collects anonymous analytics.
Read the analytics documentation (and how to opt-out) here:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics
No analytics have been recorded yet (nor will be during this `brew` run).

==> Homebrew is run entirely by unpaid volunteers. Please consider donating:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew#donations

==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).

You have 7 outdated formulae installed.

Warning: You are using macOS 10.15.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this old version.
It is expected behaviour that Homebrew will be buggy and slow.
Do not create any issues about this on Homebrew's GitHub repositories.
Do not create any issues even if you think this message is unrelated.
Any opened issues will be immediately closed without response.
Do not ask for help from Homebrew or its maintainers on social media.
You may ask for help in Homebrew's discussions but are unlikely to receive a response.
Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request.
We will review it but may or may not accept it.

==> Fetching dependencies for cocoapods: pkg-config, m4, autoconf, bison, cmake, ninja, mpdecimal, ca-certificates, openssl@3, readline, sqlite, xz, python@3.11, rust, libyaml and ruby
==> Fetching pkg-config
==> Downloading https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/homebrew-bottles//pkg-config-0.29.2_3.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
#################################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Fetching m4
==> Downloading https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/homebrew-bottles//m4-1.4.19.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
#################################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Fetching autoconf
==> Downloading https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/homebrew-bottles//autoconf-2.71.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
#################################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Fetching bison
==> Downloading https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/homebrew-bottles//bison-3.8.2.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
#################################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Fetching cmake
Error: cocoapods: Failed to download resource "cmake"
Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/4.1.4-30-g1a8f1be\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 10.15.7\)\ curl/7.64.1 --header Accept-Language:\ en --retry 3 --fail --location --silent --head https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.27.1/cmake-3.27.1.tar.gz` exited with 35. Here's the output:
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443
```

[image]

If this cannot be installed, React native cannot run